# Cannot clear input field

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm creating a filtered table in JavaScript. Everything is okay. However, the only line that doesn't seem to work is `inputValue = ''`. Not sure why it **doesn't want to clear the field** after filtering is done.

If you replace that with `document.querySelector('.form__input').value` things seem to work, but I don't want to repeat the same code. I already declared it above as `inputValue`.

```js
const initValues = [
 'Walmart',
 'State Grid',
 'Sinopec Group',
 'China National Petrolium',
 'Royal Dutch Shell',
 'Toyota Motor',
 'Volkswagen',
 'BP',
 'Exxon Mobil',
 'Berkshire Hathaway'
];

const tableCreation = array => {
 const tableBody = document.querySelector('.table__body');
 document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el));
 array.forEach(el => {
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  const cell = document.createElement('td');
  const cellText = document.createTextNode(el);
  cell.appendChild(cellText);
  row.appendChild(cell);
  tableBody.appendChild(row);
 });
};

tableCreation(initValues);

const filterTable = event => {
 event.preventDefault();
 let inputValue = document.querySelector('.form__input').value;
 const filtered = initValues.filter(el => el.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()));
 if (filtered) {
  inputValue ? tableCreation(filtered) : tableCreation(initValues);
 }
 inputValue = '';
};

document.querySelector('.form__button').addEventListener('click', filterTable);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/3.css">
 <title>Filtered list</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="form" id="form">
  <label for="filter">Filtered: </label>
  <input class="form__input" type="text" id="filter" name="input" placeholder="Insert phrase...">
  <button class="form__button" form="form" type="submit">Filter</button>
 </form>

 <table class="table">
  <tbody class="table__body"></tbody>
 </table>

 <script src="./js/3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you expect any changes to your variable have impact on your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `inputValue` is holding only the actual value of the field, it's detached from it.

You can save a reference to the field as a variable and clean the value as follows:

```
const inp = document.querySelector('.form__input');
inp.value = '';
```

Comment: @Bart You're welcome, please accept the answer to make clear, that your question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
let inputValue = document.querySelector('.form__input').value;
```

this line return the string value of the input.
When you are trying `inputValue = '';` you are only changing the value of the variable 'inputValue' but not of the input field.

to do this juste save you field as a variable instead of it's value and then change it's value :

```
let inputField = document.querySelector('.form__input');
const filtered = initValues.filter(el => el.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()));
if (filtered) {
    inputValue ? tableCreation(filtered) : tableCreation(initValues);
}
inputField.value = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You already get value only from inputvalue., but u can't change that value so 
 get dom instance also
kindly change this code to

```
const filterTable = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let inputElement = document.querySelector('.form__input'),
        inputValue = inputElement.value;
    const filtered = initValues.filter(el => el.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()));
    if (filtered) {
        inputValue ? tableCreation(filtered) : tableCreation(initValues);
    }
    inputElement.value = '';
};
```

Comment: What is `.value`?